# C++ getting rid of Singletons: alternative to functors and static methods

Tags: c++, singleton, structure, functor

My noble quest is to get rid of singletons and static classes.

**Background:**

I have the following structures:

- Cmd
  Frequently instantiated object, it holds a name of the command (string), and functor to the static method of any class as a pointer.
  It is typically created in main classes such as Input, Console, Render, etc. and refers to methods within the class that it is created in, giving a runtime verbal interface to those methods.
  Cmds also interpret parameters in a form of a string array, where first argument is the name of the Cmd, and all consecutive strings are direct arguments for the static method being invoked. The argument count and argument array are stored in Commander, and changed before each Cmd call.
- Commander
  Commander is used to interpret string commands (which may come directly, or through Console) and it executes the Cmd which was stored in the buffer as a string (by invoking it's functor).

**Problem:**

Problem is that I am attempting to get rid of all the static classes (which I now turned into singletons for testing), and I am making the system fully modular and loosely coupled. This in turn prevents me from having static calls which Cmds could point to.

First instinct was to change the functor from a typedef into a template class, which would store an object and method, but it looks very messy and complex, and I personally am not comfortable going from:

```
Cmd::create("toggleconsole", Console::toggle);
```

To:

```
Cmd::create("toggleconsole", new FunctorObject<Console>(&Console::get(), &Console::toggle));
```

The final Cmd creation looks very obscure and misleading as to who is in charge of the Functor deallocation.

I am also in the process of moving Cmd creation from a static method call, into the Commander class, so it would look like **commander.createCmd("command_name", ...);** instead of **Cmd::create("command_name",...);** This is because Commander is no longer going to be static (or singleton), so all commands which it handles must belong to it.

I am, however, at a complete loss as to what my options/alternatives are to register Cmds, and maintain the loose coupling by allowing string commands to be issued to the Commander.

I have considered making each of the main classes derive from a CmdListener class, which would register the object with the Commander upon creation, and then during execution pass a command to all registered objects which overwrote the "onCmd(const Cmd &command)".

This leaves some unanswered questions as well: how will Cmd relay which method of class should be invoked? Keeping pointers wouldn't make sense and would be subject to high level of obscurity (as demonstrated above). Also, I wish to not reinterpret strings in onCmd method for every class that **may** handle that cmd.

It is a lot of information, but does anybody have any ideas on how to deal with this issue?

Also, all my classes must be aware of Commander and Console objects, which are no longer singleton/static. So far, I have placed them inside a Context object, and am passing it around like a little capsule. Any ideas on how to solve these post-singleton residual problems?

This project is my personal work, and I am planning to use it on my resume - hence, I do not want my potential employers to see any singletons (nor do I want to explain myself as to why, since I can prove to myself they are not truly necessary).

Thanks a ton!

edit: typography.

Comment: this is a worthy goal! However you might not want to go too far. Personally, I am comitted to remove all global variables from the programs I work on, but global constants (as would be a global Commander once the registration phase ends) don't bother me.

Comment: Good point! However, what I didn't mention is that the Commander polls the commands by strings which are sent to the buffer, and then once per main loop it executes everything. So the appropriate client must have a relevant Commander to communicate through. The described problem does not yet exist, but is anticipated once most of the components are not global (if not all of them, ideally).
I will think through your suggestion again, you may have a valid point still!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a job for the `function` class. You can find one in Boost, or in TR1 or C++0x. It looks like `std::function<void()>`, for example. This is often partnered with `bind`, which you will need if you want to *refer* to functional objects in a generic way, rather than take them by value, and is also found in Boost, TR1 or C++0x. If you have lambda functions, you can use them too, which is an excellent method.

```
class Commander {
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> commands;
public:
    void RegisterCommand(std::string name, std::function<void()> cmd) {
        commands[name] = cmd;
    }
    void CallCommand(std::string name) {
        commands[name]();
    }
};
void sampleFunc() {
    std::cout << "sampleFunc()" << std::endl;
}
struct sampleStruct {
    int i;
    void operator()() {
        std::cout << i;
        std::cout << "sampleStruct()() and the value of i is " << i << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Commander c;
    c.RegisterCommand("sampleFunc", sampleFunc);
    sampleStruct instance;
    instance.i = 5;
    c.RegisterCommand("sampleStruct", instance);
    std::string command;
    while(std::cin >> command && command != "exit") {
        c.CallCommand(command);
    }
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate the response!

Following up: please assume that sampleStruct is a sampleClass, and contains multiple methods. Can std::function point to a specific method? Currently it only points to an overloaded () operator, but what about other methods?

Comment: @Kaa Combine `std::function` with `std::bind` to obtain what you want.

Comment: @Kaa: As Luc Danton said, `std::bind` exists to solve that problem.